# Android bitmap saving error. saving image is wrong , update gallery after saving image to sd card

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I created a function to save a selected image from gallery.I realize that when the image is saved for the first time it is ok.But if the process start again, it seems that the image is saved (with the same name) but the image don't change in the explorer.It just keep the old bitmap image.I tested on two different devices but the same result.Actually on an Infinix hot 7 but same result.

```
public static String saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, File[] folders, File file, Context context) {

    for (File folder:folders) {
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    if (file.exists ()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image: Green tree image]

[image: Red tree image]

You can see that i chose a photo of green nature but it registers an old red tree photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After saving the image in gallery you should update image to the system for gallery and file explorer

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(myNewFile)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much.This worked for the gallery but not for the explorer.

Comment: okay im glad it worked and check the file in different file explorer like es file explorer etc

Comment: Thank you.it works with some explorer but not in some

Comment: well i knew because it also depends on file explorer which you are using . thats the problem with explorer